# SELECTing all ids FROM a MySQL query but with a limitation?

Tags: php, mysql, aggregate-functions

I have the following MySQL query:

```
SELECT SUM(IF(num_content>3,3,num_content)) 
FROM
(
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(content_timestamp)) as dt, COUNT(id) as num_content
FROM content     
WHERE author = 'newbtophp'
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(content_timestamp))
)a
```

Which returns the a count of content (from a specific content author) but with the following restriction => it will only consider a maximum of 3 rows of data per day (using the `content_timestamp`).

It is working fine, however now I'm wanting to return all ids (do a `query` then a `while loop` with `mysql_fetch_assoc`) which fall under that restriction, I've tried the following query:

```
SELECT id 
FROM
(
SELECT DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(content_timestamp)) as dt, COUNT(id) as num_content, id      FROM content     
WHERE author = 'newbtophp'
GROUP BY DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(content_timestamp))
)a
```

But no luck (as its not returning the ids with the restriction).

The main issue for me is I'm not sure how to integrate the restriction whilst returning the ids.

I appreciate all responses.

Comment: When you select from a derived table, you cannot select fields which are not returned by the inner query. The subquery is essentialy treated as its own table in the db. You can't select an 'id' field from it, as the query doesn't return a field named "id". You can only select 'dt' or 'num_content'

Comment: Thanks @MarcB I've just tried adding the id to the subquery but still no luck :/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There certainly must exist a more efficient solution (JOIN), but the following is readable:

```
SELECT id, content_timestamp
FROM content c
WHERE author = 'newbtophp'
AND (SELECT COUNT(*)
     FROM content
     WHERE DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(content_timestamp)) = DATE(FROM_UNIXTIME(c.content_timestamp))
     AND content_timestamp < c.content_timestamp
    ) < 3
ORDER BY content_timestamp
```